# Xcode 4.4.1 code signing issue

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.4, code-signing-entitlements

I have this code signing issue that came up only recently when I tried to submit my Mac application (*not* iOS) with Xcode 4.4.1

When I tried to validate my app's archive, validation fails with these two errors:

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the  ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: 'com.(mycompany).(myapp)' for the key 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'MyAppBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppExecutable'
>
> Invalid code signing entitlements. Your application's bundle signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X. Specifically, value 'com.(mycompany).(myapp)' for key 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'MyAppBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppExecutable' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.' followed by the bundle identifier.
>
> This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the OS.

I've tried the following but none of them worked:

- re-downloading and re-generating code signing certificates.
- Specifying my team ID in the code signing parameters:
      -i "(TEAMID).com.(mycompany).(myapp)" --entitlements "(MyAppEntitlementFile).entitlements"

[image: Actual Xcode screenshot]

Anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this by editing my entitlements file using Xcode's property list editor (*not* the fancy-looking GUI in the target's `Summary` tab) and remove the key named `com.apple.application-identifier` along with its value.

I'm not sure how that key-value pair got there in the first place because I'm quite confident that I didn't put it in there myself. This project was originally coded for Snow Leopard without sandboxing and went through a number of Xcode versions. Perhaps an old version of Xcode put it there and it conflicted with the newer one.